# Android Studio Installation Error on MacBook M1 Pro: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I am trying to install Android Studio on my MacBook M1 Pro. I downloaded the 'Giraffe' version of Android Studio and successfully executed the .dmg file to place it in the Applications folder. However, when I try to launch Android Studio from the Applications folder, I encounter the following error:[image]

Has anyone experienced this issue or know how to resolve it? Detailed explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue when i first installed it, try typing this into the terminal

sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio

It worked when I ran the progam as a super user.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following folder and try again. This was my issue for both Chrome and Android Studio.

```
Users/<usr name>/Library/Application Support/Google
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error, I tried your solution but I was not sure if it will give me more problems in the future.. so I remind previously I installed Google Chrome with a third party app in Mac before install Android Studio and after uninstall Chrome and folder created by it the issue was fixed.

I followed the nexts steps:

1. Uninstalled chrome using same way I installed it. (Third party app in my case)
2. Then using Finder with Go To option I navigated to “/Users/myUser/Library/Application Supoort/Google“ then I checked the folder still existing.
3. Navigate one folder back to be on application support folder then I deleted Google folder. After I accepted confirmation for delete that folder it was deleted.
4. I proceed to launch Android Studio again and it was launched without issues.

Hope this helps others to fix the issue or give idea on how to solve it.